# How to know what to add to *.pro file in QT project when including new library?

Tags: qt, setup-project

While doing some newbie development in Qt I faced with challenge to understand what to add to my *.pro file.
For example, I'm adding `#include <QDomDocument>`. After save it starts saying that

> error: QDomDocument: No such file or directory

. I go to Google, past this error and find on Stackoverflow what to add to my .pro file.

How this `QT += xml` is named and where to find it in documentation?

Comment: It's named **module**. Qt is divided into modules and with `QT += ...` you tell qmake which modules to use. This will add the directories to the include path (so `#include` finds the files) as well as link against the module library (every module is a library which has to be linked to the executable).

Comment: You can see the modules for Qt 4.8 [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modules.html). For Qt 5 you can see them [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmodules.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try search something about `Qt` in `Qt Creator` help:

1. Press `Help` (left side)
2. Type `qdomdocument` in `Search for`:
3. Choose `QDomDocument` class.

Now you see this table:

```
Header: #include <QDomDocument>
qmake:  QT += xml
Inherits:   QDomNode.
```

It is answer, you can find it in documentation. And you'll know where you should search.

Of course you can find this in Internet, but for example:

This link has qmake line:    http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdomdocument.html

This link hasn't qmake line: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html

`Help` in `Qt Creator` always gives you actual info, but `Google` first of all give you qt-4.8 documentation.